# How do I add the SVN add-on Subclipse to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am trying to install Subclipse plugins for eclipse IDE.
I have installed it but on restart of the IDE, it throws up the following error:

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
```

How do I get past this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it worked out. Very simple solution. Just added

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
```

after `-vmargs` in eclipse.ini file and restarted the IDE.

This solution won't work if you did a manual installation of eclipse, for example if you wanted to use a newer version than the one on the software centre

Comment: Why do you say that it won't work with a manual installation? This is actually the recommended way to do it (http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-bb1dd50f9ec2f0d8c32246430c00e237d27a04fe)

Comment: On my 12.04 64bit I had to find the file with 'find / -name libsvnjavahl-1.so' in '-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni' instead.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to be sure that `libsvn-java` is installed (see [subclipse
Wiki: JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-bb1dd50f9ec2f0d8c32246430c00e237d27a04fe)):

> apt-get install libsvn-java

Answer (score 1):

If you are running "manually installed" version of Eclipse you can just provide path as runtime parameter.

```
eclipse -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
```

Or better yet, create shell script and launcher that runs it.
I setup my Eclipse environment like this:

- I download latest and greatest version of Eclipse (at the moment eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)
- Per version I unpack it to ~/bin/eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64/
- I create a soft link with the name *eclipse* to previously named unpacked directory:

  ```
  cd ~/bin/ 
  ln -s eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64 eclipse
  ```
- I create **eclipse.sh** script in *~/bin/eclipse/*

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # the following is not really needed but is nice if you put script somewhere else (like Desktop)
  cd ~/bin/eclipse/
  # this fixes the menu items not showing bug
  export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
  # add the jni library path
  ./eclipse -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
  ```